# Прошу помочь с функцией def при работе с массивами. Python

Tags: python, массивы, функции

Прошу помочь в решении задачи:

> Заполнить двумерный массив случайными целыми числами (функция).
>
> Найти наибольший (функция) и наименьший (функция) элементы массива и,
>   чередуя, заполнить ими одномерный массив заданной размерности.
>
> Вывести исходный (функция) и одномерный (функция) массивы на экран. (
>   max, min считает правильно через раз).

Подскажите как закончить.

```
from random import random
N = 3
M = 4
mtx = []
arr = [0] * N*M

for i in range(N):
    a = []
    for j in range(M):
        a.append(int(random()*100))
    mtx.append(a)

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        print("%3d" % mtx[i][j], end='')
    print()
print()

k = -1
for j in range(M):
    for i in range(N):
        k += 1
        arr[k] = mtx[i][j]
        print("%3d" % arr[k], end='')
print()
def search_min(a):
    el_min = a[0]
    for elm in a[1:]:
        if elm < el_min:
            el_min = elm
    print('min:' + str(el_min))

def search_max(a):
    el_max = a[0]
    for elm in a[1:]:
        if elm > el_max:
            el_max = elm
    print('max:' + str(el_max))

search_min(a)
search_max(a)
```

> == RESTART: C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\7777.py ==
>    11 51 62 57
>    17 79 89 96
>    40 76 74  3

11 17 40 51 79 76 62 89 74 57 96  3
min:3
max:76

> == RESTART: C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\7777.py ==
>    96  8 58 53
>    53 24 71 78
>    58 13 45 77

96 53 58  8 24 13 58 71 45 53 78 77
min:13
max:77

> == RESTART: C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\7777.py ==
>    75 59 97 75
>    67 23 34 41
>    71 84 60 92

75 67 71 59 23 84 97 34 60 75 41 92
min:60
max:92

Answer (score 2):

Какие-то примечания и правки (в конце полная программа):

1. Ваш массив должен быть *двухмерным* — значит, он должен быть *списком списков*, в котором всякой внутренний список будет строкой матрицы. Например:

   ```
   [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]    # матрица 3x2, т.е. 3 строки и 2 столбцы
   ```
2. Вместо сложного `int(random()*100)` возможно использовать *другую* функцию из модуля random, именно randint():

   ```
   from random import randint
   randint(0, 99)           # генерирует случайное число от 0 до 99 (включительно 0 и 99)
   ```
3. Значит, код для задания

   > Заполнить двумерный массив случайными целыми числами (функция)

   может быть например такой (всё, что я пишу, я и тестировал):

   ```
   from random import randint

   M = 3
   N = 4
   N_VEC = 7      # Размерность одномерного массива; пока не используем (но в конце да)
   FROM = 0
   TO = 99

   def fill_matrix():
       matrix = []
       for __ in range(M):
           row = []
           for __ in range(N):
               row.append(randint(FROM, TO))
           matrix.append(row)
       return matrix
   ```

   *Чудесное имя переменной* `__` (два символа нижнего подчеркивания) в циклах `for` подсказывает, что эта переменная в дальнейшем *не будет использована* (но какое-то имя нужно для правильного синтаксиса).

   (Возможно применить и «нормальные» имена, например `m` и `n`, но в Питоне такая обычай.)
4. Так как наибольший и наименьший элемент лучше определить из *одномерного массива (списка)* чем из двухмерного (матрицы), напишем функцию для перевода матрицы в список:

   ```
   def matrix_to_list(matrix):
       result = []
       for row in matrix:
           result += row
       return result
   ```
5. Написать функции для наибольшего и наименьшего элемента будет теперь очень просто — переведем матрицу в список и применим стандартную функцию `max()` или `min()`:

   ```
   def maximum(matrix):
       lst = matrix_to_list(matrix)
       return max(lst)


   def minimum(matrix):
       lst = matrix_to_list(matrix)
       return min(lst)
   ```
6. Для заполнения одномерного массива (т.е. списка) размерности `n` чередующими значениями `a` и `b` возможно поступать например так:

   ```
   def fill_alternately(n, a, b):
       result = [a]
       for __ in range(1, n):
           if result[-1] == a:
               result.append(b)
           else:
               result.append(a)
       return result
   ```
7. Функции для вывода на экран напишем так, что сначала будет функция для вывода одномерного массива (списка), которую затем применим в определении функции для вывода двухмерного массива (матрицы):

   ```
   def list_out(lst):
       for val in lst:
           print(f'{val:3}', end='')
       print()


   def matrix_out(matrix):
       for row in matrix:
           list_out(row)
   ```

Но и теперь у вас уже все нужные функции, остается только применить их (т.е. вызвать их с подходящими параметрами):

```
matrix = fill_matrix()
min_val = minimum(matrix)
max_val = maximum(matrix)
vector = fill_alternately(N_VEC, max_val, min_val)

matrix_out(matrix)
print()
list_out(vector)
```

---

Полная программа:

```
from random import randint

M = 3        
N = 4 
N_VEC = 7
FROM = 0
TO = 99

def fill_matrix():
    matrix = []
    for __ in range(M):
        row = []
        for __ in range(N):
            row.append(randint(FROM, TO))
        matrix.append(row)
    return matrix

def matrix_to_list(matrix):
    result = []
    for row in matrix:
        result += row
    return result

def maximum(matrix):
    lst = matrix_to_list(matrix)
    return max(lst)

def minimum(matrix):
    lst = matrix_to_list(matrix)
    return min(lst)

def fill_alternately(n, a, b):
    result = [a]
    for __ in range(1, n):
        if result[-1] == a:
            result.append(b)
        else:
            result.append(a)
    return result

def list_out(lst):
    for val in lst:
        print(f'{val:3}', end='')
    print()

def matrix_out(matrix):
    for row in matrix:
        list_out(row)

matrix = fill_matrix()
min_val = minimum(matrix)
max_val = maximum(matrix)
vector = fill_alternately(N_VEC, max_val, min_val)

matrix_out(matrix)
print()
list_out(vector)
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение.

Comment: @sashha, не стоит. Но когда был мой ответ для вас полезным, вы можете голосовать за него (клик на треугольник вверх у его начала) и / или принять его (клик на галочку).

Answer (score 0):

```py
from random import randint
N = 3
M = 4

arr = [0] * N*M

def create_matrix_rand(n = N, m = M):
  matrix = []
  for i in range(0, N):
    matrix.append([])
    for _ in range(0, M):
      matrix[i].append(randint(0, 1000))

  return matrix

matrix = create_matrix_rand()

def find_min(matrix = matrix):
  min = matrix[0][0]
  for row in matrix:
    for el in row:
      if el < min:
        min = el

  return min

def find_max(matrix = matrix):
  max = matrix[0][0]
  for row in matrix:
    for el in row:
      if el > max:
        max = el

  return max

def print_matrix(matrix = matrix):
  for row in matrix:
    for el in row:
      print(el, end=" ")
    print()

def create_list_of_max_min(lst_length = len(matrix) * len(matrix[0])):
  lst = []
  max = find_max()
  min = find_min()

  for i in range(0, lst_length):
    if i % 2 == 0:
      lst.append(max)
    else:
      lst.append(min)

  return lst

def print_list(lst):
  for el in lst:
    print(el, end=" ")

print(f"Исходная матрица: ")
print_matrix()

print(end="\n\n\n")

min = find_min()
print(f"Минимальное значение: {min}", end="\n\n\n")

max = find_max()
print(f"Максимальное значение: {max}", end="\n\n\n")

one_dimensional = create_list_of_max_min()
print("Одномерный массив заполненный максимальными и минимальными элементами: ")
print_list(one_dimensional)
```